# Fullcalendar not showing codeigniter file

Tags: codeigniter, fullcalendar

My view load.php:

```
<?php

$all = $this->db->get_where('project', array('institution_id' => $this->session->userdata('institution_id')))->result_array();

$data = array();

foreach($all as $row)
{
 $data[] = array(
  'id'   => $row["project_code"],
  'title'   => $row["description"],
  'start'   => date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $row["timestamp_start"]),
  'end'   => date('d-M-Y H:i:s', $row["timestamp_end"])
 );
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

However, it doesnt display with my Fullcalendar. Which is at:

```
 events: 'https://xxxxxxx.com.au/index.php?staff/load/',
```

The view that you requested. The events is gotten from load.php which is at the start of this post.

```
<div id="calendar" class="fc-calendar"></div>

  <script>

  $(document).ready(function() {
   var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    editable:true,
    header:{
     left:'prev,next today',
     center:'title',
     right:'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: 'https://panel.strater.com.au/index.php?staff/load/',

   });
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: What? I'm having trouble following any of this. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Where is your calendar? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: So the load.php works perfectly, but when I try load the calendar on a seperate page and pull the events from the load.php it doesn't load.

Comment: And what troubleshooting steps have you taken?

Comment: None, I don't even see how it's an issue. The page when loaded through the URL gives me the correct json output. It's like the page with the calendar on it isn't able to read the json.

Comment: If that were the case then it should give you some kind of parsing error in the console? It would also be useful if you could add a minimal example of your view including js code.

Comment: @Alex added the view at the end of the post, thanks mate

Comment: @Alex Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: A 404? Are you sure that you have a controller called staff that had a method load?

Comment: Yes there is one

Comment: 400 bad request means the request you sent to the server was invalid in some way. Learn how you use your browser's developer tools to debug the ajax request which fullCalendar is making. We can't, from here, see enough of the necessary info. On the face of it, your code is probably ok, but perhaps there's something else happening which codeigniter doesn't like or isn't configured properly for

Comment: One observation though....in your text and comments you refer to "load.php" several times, but you URL ends "index.php?staff/load/"...so not "load.php" at all. Are you sure you URL is correct?

Comment: The controller for load.php is this "index.php?staff/load/". "index.php?staff/load/" shows exactly what load.php would.